# Get Full State Name Instead of Abbreviation in React 50 State Map

Tags: reactjs

I am using this project for the react map: https://github.com/gabidavila/react-usa-map
Here is a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-christian-9gzcjx

I have a similar react project but thought posting that example would be easier.

```
  mapHandler = event => {
alert(event.target.dataset.name);
```

};

For this event handler, I would like to alert the full state name instead of the abbreviation.In my actual project, I am setting the state based on what the user clicks on and using that to dynamically filter a grid. Problem is that the items in the grid are full state names instead of abbreviations.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to read their documentation and see if they support full names.
If they seem to only support abbreviations, you may need your own mappings.

What that means is, you may take the abbreviation from `event.target.dataset.name` and map it into an object that contains the full name. Something like this:

```
const stateMappings = { NY: 'New York', CA: 'California'}
```

You can add more to the object above.
Then we can do a lookup in the object like so:

```
alert(stateMappings[event.target.dataset.name]);
```

Full code:

```
mapHandler = event => {
    alert(stateMappings[event.target.dataset.name]);
}
```